# Projection Operator Self-Adjointness

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Is it right to say that projection operator is not self-adjoint(Hermitian) if it is not orthogonal projection operator?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I think both of us can learn from Robert answer

Answer (score 0):

A projection operator $P$ is by definition [orthogonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) if and only if

$\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle \tag 1$

for all vectors $x$, $y$; if (1) binds then

$\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle = \langle P^\dagger x, y \rangle, \tag 2$

whence

$Px = P^\dagger x, \tag 3$

or

$P = P^\dagger, \tag 4$

that is, $P$ is self-adjoint.  The argument may be reversed:  (4) clearly implies (3); thus

$\langle Px, y \rangle =  \langle P^\dagger x, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle, \tag 5$

so $P$ is orthogonal.

Since we have shown that a projection operator is orthogonal if and only if it is self-adjoint, we conclude that if $P$ is not orthognonal, then $P$ is not self-adjoint.